# How to animate cards list with z-index?

Tags: jquery, css-animations

I need to add animation to a list of cards. Animation can be any but the problem is the background of the card changes. The active card has one background, the inactive one has another. What animation can be added here?

I tried to add a transition and change the transparency of the background but it turns out very ugly.

[Here what I have now](https://codepen.io/Nnekkka/pen/qBQoGOY)

```js
const list = [...document.querySelectorAll('.list__item')]

if (list) {
    list.forEach((item, idx) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', function () {
            const active = document.querySelector('.active');
            active.classList.remove('active');
            item.classList.add('active');
            const prevElements = [...$('.active').prevAll()];
            const nextElements = [...$('.active').nextAll()];
            setClasses(prevElements, nextElements);
        })
    })
}

const setClasses = (prev, next) => {
    prev.forEach((item, idx) => {
        item.classList.add('prev');
        item.style.zIndex = `${5 - idx}`;
    })
    next.forEach((item, idx) => {
        item.classList.remove('prev');
        item.style.zIndex = `${5 - idx}`;
    })
}
```

```css
.list {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.list__item {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('https://www.alleycat.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/FELV-cat.jpg');
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-position: right;
    border-radius: 45px;
    box-shadow: 8px 4px 11px 0 rgba(70, 121, 226, 0.22);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.list__item.prev {
    background-position: left;
}

.list__item::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.theatlantic.com/thumbor/B7U27JF25tScMZkCe5Pl9EqXjao=/0x131:2555x1568/960x540/media/img/mt/2017/06/shutterstock_319985324/original.jpg');
    opacity: 0;
}

.list__item.active {
    z-index: 9 !important;
}

.active.list__item::before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.list__item:nth-child(1) {
    right: 180px;
}

.list__item:nth-child(2) {
    right: 120px;
    z-index: 4;
}

.list__item:nth-child(3) {
    right: 60px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.list__item:nth-child(4) {
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
                    <li class="list__item active">

                    </li>
                    <li class="list__item">

                    </li>
                    <li class="list__item">

                    </li>
                    <li class="list__item">

                    </li>
                </ul>
```